# how to insert edittext data in database

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to store a data in database of new user.I am read more more answer from this site.but i don't understand how to solve this error, my app is unfortunatly closed.

```
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): Process:                                            

com.jogatiservices.numbersinfo, PID: 1032
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at    
 com.jogatiservices.numbersinfo.RegisterActivity$2.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:64)
  09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):   at                           
 android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
 09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):    at   
 android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
 09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):    at    
 android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
 09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at  
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at    
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at       
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at      
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run         
(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at    
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-03 03:24:44.316: E/AndroidRuntime(1032):     at    
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my code is

Adapter class

```
public void insertEntry(String fullname, String email, String password)
            {
               ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
                // Assign values for each row.
                newValues.put("USERNAME", fullname);
                newValues.put("EMAILID", email);
                newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

                // Insert the row into your table
                db.insert("USERSINFO", null, newValues);
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Register class

```
Button btnregister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnregister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    // getting database for reading/writing purpose
        db=dataBaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        String fullname=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
        String password=editTextPassword.getText().toString();
        String email=editTextEmail.getText().toString();
        String confirmPassword=editTextConfirmPassword.getText().toString();

        // check if any of the fields are empty or not
        if(fullname.equals("")||email.equals("")||password.equals("")||confirmPassword.equals(""))
        {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill The Empty Field", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
        }
        else if(!password.equals(confirmPassword))
        {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password does not match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;

        }

        else
        {

            loginDataBaseAdapter.insertEntry(fullname, email, password);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Account Successfully Created ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
});

loginDataBaseAdapter.close();       
}
```

Comment: There are NullPointerException in line 64... May be you made a mistake in button ID. Show us line 64 of RegisterActivity

Answer (score 0):

You get a NullPointerException. That means that you are trying to call a method on a null object. The line is the line in the file that fails

```
(om.jogatiservices.numbersinfo.RegisterActivity$2.onClick(RegisterActivity.java:64) -> line 64 in RegisterActivity), but I don't know exactly which line that is.
```

However I see a few problems.

```
String fullname=editTextUserName.getText().toString();
```

What happens if `getText()` is null, i.e. if the field is empty?

```
fullname.equals("")
```

This is also bad practice (but it won't fail here, I think). If you do `"".equals(fullname)` you are safe and this will never fail (since "" is never null). You way will fail if fullname somehow ends up being null.

Answer (score 0):

check your fields like this

```
if(fullname!=null) || .....)
```

use it like this.

```
public void insertEntry(String fullname, String email, String password)
        {

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();
            // Assign values for each row.
            newValues.put("USERNAME", fullname);
            newValues.put("EMAILID", email);
            newValues.put("PASSWORD",password);

            // Insert the row into your table
            db.insert("USERSINFO", null, newValues);
            //Toast.makeText(context, "Reminder Is Successfully Saved", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        db.close();
    }
```

and don't open database outside(bcoz need to close it after action) function.

also use AsyncTask for database or network operation that is better approach.